# Is a police clearance certificate a relevant document for foreigners coming to Germany?

Tags: germany

As a student coming to Germany, I would like to ask if a police clearance certificate is relevant to any procedures, eg: Anmeldung, Aufenthaltstitel, enrollment and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a police certificate is not relevant nor required for Anmeldung, application for a Residence permit, or Enrollment at University.

Source: I lived in Germany for > 5 years, as student and worker.

Comment: A **Führungszeugnis** can be required by an employer for certain positions of high trust **or** for any position that regulary deals with underage children. For the first for periods up to 5 years ('simple') for the second for periods greater 5 years ('extended').

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your description, a police clearance certificate is a background check?
I was never asked for such a document nor were any of my family members because we are citizens of the European Union. (Probably they can make the background checks)

I can tell you for sure that if you are coming from a European country that is not part of European Union, and you need to apply for visa in order to work or study in Germany, then you will have to have this Document prior to obtaining the visa.

Comment: I didn't need it when applying for the visa as an Indian citizen. Maybe worth mentioning that I also got the visa a few days ago.